# Composer out of memory after upgrade Sylius from 1.1.6 to 1.2.9

Tags: symfony, xampp, composer-php, sylius

I have followed the instruction to upgrade Sylius from 1.1.6 to 1.2.9:
https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/blob/master/UPGRADE-1.2.md

Now, composer no longer working with error: out of memory

I have already set to memory_limit=-1 (unlimited) in php.ini

And composer working fine on another folder (I have install new Sylius with no issue)

My env:
Windows, Xampp, PHP 7.2.7, Symfony 3.4.18
composer v1.8.0

Anyone could help?

Comment: How much memory does your machine have?

Also, can you run the update command with --profile to see where the biggest jumps in memory are made?

Comment: 8Gb ram. Result: `[7.5MB/0.01s] Loading composer repositories with package information
[7.9MB/1.17s] Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
VirtualAlloc() failed: [0x00000008] Not enough storage is available to process this command.
VirtualAlloc() failed: [0x00000008] Not enough storage is available to process this command.
PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 910163968) (tried to allocate 117440512 bytes) in phar://C:/xampp/htdocs/my folder/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleSet.php on line 90`

Comment: Xampp only shipps with a 32-bit PHP binary. This can cause issues with big composer files. Maybe try to install php directly on your windows host and use the 64-bit version.

Answer (score 1):

Try this maybe can help you :

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 composer.phar update
```

Comment: Finally I installed a newer version and migrate my changers. Seems some issue on v1.2.9 (on Windows with Xampp)